# Skylink IOS issue when disconnect the room

Tags: skylink

I'm working on SkylinkJS for IOS version. On website, it's good. Everything runs correctly. But on IOS, I write the app by Swift.

Everything is good too except the app just crash sometime while trying to disconnect from the room. And I know for sure this error is from the room disconnection. Because If I just go to that viewcontroller and don't connect to any room or just connect to that room and leave without disconnection. Everything will be ok.

The error is:

```
2017-01-09 13:51:49.187237 Star Dial[8187:3318041] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1834c11b8 0x181ef855c 0x1833a4eac 0x1833a4d1c 0x1001bba70 0x102689218 0x102695a90 0x1001b7ee4 0x102689258 0x102689218 0x102696aec 0x10268cce0 0x102697088 0x102698e2c 0x102698b78 0x1825532a0 0x182552d8c)
```

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

The code from button disconnect:

```
if self.skylinkConn != nil {
        self.skylinkConn?.disconnect({

            print(">>> PROFILE DISCONNECTED")

            if profile_before == "home" {
                profile_before  = ""
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else if profile_before == "following" || profile_before == "follower" {
                profile_before  = ""
                self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                profile_before  = ""
                let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let next    = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeView") as! HomeController
                self.present(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        })
}
```

profile_before is from root class. So it's not the reason. The weird thing is that this error only happens sometime... like when I open this controller 30, 40 times, it will be crash one time... and sometime, I open this page about 100 times and crash.

And for sure, it's not because of the memories too. I check the memory, average during that time is 20-30 MB

Answer (score 0):

I am working in the Temasys Engineering team. The described issue has been resolved. If anyone encounter the problem again please make sure the Temasys SDK for iOS is up to date.